# Kotlin-multiplatform: How to execute iOS unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin-multiplatform library for Android and iOS. I want to write some platform-specific unit test. The tests run as expected for the shared code and Android but not for iOS.

Below the `build.gradle` file of the shared code module.

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-multiplatform"

kotlin {
    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos") \
                              ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') {
            compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        }

        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common"
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
        }
        androidTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
                implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
            }
        }
        iOSMain.dependencies {
        }
        iOSTest.dependencies {
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit'
        }
    }
}

// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

task packForXCode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.linkTaskName("FRAMEWORK", mode)

    from { kotlin.targets.iOS.compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", mode).parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXCode
```

and the structure of the `SharedCode` module is:

```
└── src
    ├── commonMain
    │   └── kotlin
    ├── commonTest
    │   └── kotlin
    ├── androidMain
    │   └── kotlin
    ├── androidTest
    │   └── kotlin
    ├── iOSMain
    │   └── kotlin
    └── iOSTest
        └── kotlin
```

The tests added in the `androidTest` and `commonTest` folders do run as expected but the ones added in the `iOSTest` do not run.

However, if I replace the the line `fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'iOS') { compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK') }` for `fromPreset(presets.macosX64, 'macos')` and update the directory names accordly, the tests in the `macosTest` folder do run as expected.

Why it is not possible to run iOS test when building iOS frameworks? Any idea about what I'm doing wrong or how I can make this works? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin supports only running tests for host platforms (e.g. macOS or Windows). But you can manually add a task for executing iOS tests on a simualtor:

```
task iosTest {
    def device = project.findProperty("iosDevice")?.toString() ?: "iPhone 8"
    dependsOn 'linkTestDebugExecutableIos'
    group = JavaBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP
    description = "Runs tests for target 'ios' on an iOS simulator"

    doLast {
        def binary = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getExecutable('test', 'DEBUG').outputFile
        exec {
            commandLine 'xcrun', 'simctl', 'spawn', device, binary.absolutePath
        }
    }
}
```

See the full build script [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-mpp-example/blob/0ace750ffd2ccb8dd4adf40f26b4d6ecc462c06a/greeting/build.gradle#L87).

Comment: Awesome, @IlyaMatveev this is what I was looking for. Thanks! :D

Comment: Does it open ios simulator and run a tests? In my case it doesn't open ios simulator as it do when i run a tests in xcode project.

Comment: @mkkrolik, no, it does not open the device simulator but tests are executed in the simulator's process.

Answer (score 4):

As I ran into some issues, I'll post my solution here.

With Kotlin `1.3.50` and XCode `11` I had to change my command line arguments:

```
val iosTest: Task by tasks.creating {
    val device = project.findProperty("iosDevice")?.toString() ?: "iPhone 8"
    val testExecutable = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("iosX64").binaries.getTest("DEBUG")
    dependsOn(testExecutable.linkTaskName)
    group = JavaBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP
    description = "Runs tests for target 'ios' on an iOS simulator"

    doLast {
        exec {
            println(testExecutable.outputFile.absolutePath)
            commandLine( "xcrun", "simctl", "spawn", "--standalone", device, testExecutable.outputFile.absolutePath)
        }
    }
}

tasks.getByName("allTests").dependsOn(iosTest)
```

Comment: this should be marked as answer for latest version of kotlin and xcode

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @IlyaMatveev works perfect for me. But I had to updates two lines  using Kotlin Version 1.3.41:

`dependsOn 'linkTestDebugExecutableIos'`
is now
`dependsOn 'linkDebugTestIos'`

`def binary = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getExecutable('test', 'DEBUG').outputFile`
is now `def binary = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getTest("DEBUG").outputFile`